# Mean index.ejs not rendering angular

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

Im new to MEAN and Im struck with the implementation of login page. In my login page I have a ng-model bind to input of username

index.ejs
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                    check

```
            <% if(locals.error) { %>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= error %></div>
            <% } %>
            <% if(locals.success) { %>
                <div class="alert alert-success"><%= success %></div>
            <% } %>

                <form id='contactForm' method='post'>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="name" name="username">{{name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="pass" name="password" ng-model="pass">{{pass}}
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-style">LOGIN</button>
                    <a href="/register" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-style">REGISTER</a>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By doing so I dont see ng-model is binding data
[image]

Any help in binding data would be helpful

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No error in console...!

Comment: I think you haven't included the angular plugin. Or you havent added ng-app.Can you include the whole code with ng-app?